# Is there a way to colour rows that have an idetical value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to automatically colour rows the same colour if they have a field (like ID) that is the same?

So something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KJBu.png)

Comment: You can use Conditional Formatting but if your data is large you should provide your data sample.

Answer (score 1):

From the article
[How to color duplicate values or duplicate rows in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3080-excel-color-duplicates.html)

**Color the duplicate values**

1. Select the data range you want to color the duplicate values, then click *Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Duplicate Values*.
2. In the dialog, select the color for highlighting duplicates
3. Click OK.

**Color duplicate rows in the selected range**

1. Select the data range and click *Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule*
2. Then in the *New Formatting Rule* dialog, select
   *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* in the section of
   *Select a Rule Type:*, then type this formula to the text box under
   *Format values where this formula is true*:

   ```
   =COUNTIF($D$2:$D$10,$D2)>1
   ```

   (D2:D10 is the column range you find duplicates from, and D2 is the first cell of the column range)
3. Click *Format* to go to the *Format Cells* dialog, and under the *Fill* tab,
   select a color for the duplicates.
4. Click OK twice.

You may find more details and screenshots in the article.